# jquery click event doesn't work with touchscreen

Tags: jquery, checkbox, touch

I'm no expert with jquery, and I'm having trouble with a reaction to a click event.
I have a form with two checkboxes, what I need is that when I click on one of them the other one is automatically unchecked. 
I wrote a jquery code that perfectly works on laptop but not on smartphone.
I have this form:

```
<form method="get" action="categorie.php">
 <input id="eatcheck" class="check" type="checkbox" name="eat&drink" value="1" />
 <input id="shopcheck" class="check" type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="1" />
 <input class="btn" id="labels-btn" type="submit" value="Aggiorna risultati">
</form>
```

and that's the script:

```
<script>
    $('#eatcheck').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('#shopcheck').attr('checked', false); }
    });
    $('#shopcheck').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('#eatcheck').attr('checked', false); }
    });    
</script>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone can help!
Margherita

Comment: Why not just use a `radio` input? They have this *exact* behaviour by default, without needing any JS to mess up the standard behaviour of the control.

Comment: the form is more complicated actually. I need it to be a checkbox...